# Arduino ESP32 not showing up in Swift/iOS CoreBluetooth app when services are advertised

Tags: arduino, core-bluetooth

I am trying to list only bluetooth devices in iOS with a certain service, but it is not showing up. I am using a [HiLetgo ESP-WROOM-32 ESP32 ESP-32S Development Board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0718T232Z) and Arduino. The Arduino code is **BLE_notify** under **ESP32 BLE Arduino** in the **ESP32 Dev Module** of the examples. It defines a service:

```
#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
```

...create it:

```
  // Create the BLE Service
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
```

...and advertises it:

```
  // Start advertising
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->addServiceUUID(SERVICE_UUID);
  pAdvertising->setScanResponse(false);
  pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x0);  // set value to 0x00 to not advertise this parameter
  BLEDevice::startAdvertising();
  Serial.println("Waiting a client connection to notify...");
```

The Swift iOS code also defines the service:

```
let serviceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")
```

...and I scan for the service:

```
self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceCBUUID])
```

but it does not appear. When I put `nil` for the `withServices`. It picks it up. I print the services:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    
    if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
        var pname: String = peripheral.name ?? "unnamed device"
        if (pname.contains("Test Device")) {
            print("Peripheral name: \(peripheral.name)")
            print("Peripheral Discovered: \(peripheral)")
            print ("Advertisement Data : \(advertisementData)")
            print ("Services : \(peripheral.services)")
        }
        self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
        self.peripheralNames.append((peripheral.name ?? "unnamed device") + " [\(peripheral.identifier)]")
    }
}
```

...and services is nil:

```
Peripheral name: Optional("Test Device")
Peripheral Discovered: <CBPeripheral: 0x283019ad0, identifier = C7D8059E-42EE-A549-9AF9-C2DC93FBD712, name = Test Device, mtu = 0, state = disconnected>
Advertisement Data : ["kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY": 0, "kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY": 129, "kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel": 3, "kCBAdvDataIsConnectable": 1, "kCBAdvDataTimestamp": 694870916.362642, "kCBAdvDataLocalName": Test Device]
Services : nil
```

When I connect to the peripheral:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    
    print("didDiscoverServices")
    guard let services = peripheral.services else {
        return
    }
    print("services count: \(services.count)")
    for service in services {
        print("service: \(service.description)")
    }
    
    discoverCharacteristics(peripheral: peripheral)
}
```

I can see the service:

```
service: <CBService: 0x281378340, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 4FAFC201-1FB5-459E-8FCC-C5C9C331914B>
```

So if it's advertising the service, why can't I filter on it? Has anybody gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `setScanResponse(false);`, this is exactly the behaviour to expect. Just remove this statement or set it to `true` if you want to advertise the service on scanning.